# Can I transfer my SO account to a new email address?

Tags: support

I am getting excessive spam on the email address I use for my SO account and would like to cancel that address  and create a new one.  Is it possible to transfer my existing SO account to a new email address while keeping all history intact?

Comment: Why don't you just change the e-mail in your current profile?

Comment: Questions related to operations and support of SO should be posted to [meta]. SO itself is for programming related questions.

Comment: @ÁlvaroG.Vicario No, I have the same issue, my login email is different from my profile email

Comment: @KenWhite - I was on the _Meta_ page when I posted this question.  I am not sure why it ended up on SO.  Appreciate the comment, but I believe I experienced a system hicup.  (perhaps pilot error)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The procedure in [the other answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/252557/1426539) is the way to go if you want to change your OpenID creds, but counterinuitively, this won't help if the problem is too many SO emails.

For that you'll want to change your email preferences, which can be done by going to your profile page and clicking on the 'preferences' link along the top of the page. There you can choose which address you receive emails at, and how often you want 'em.

Comment: I'm assuming that the OP means he's generally receiving too much spam. Not that the source is SO/SE.

Answer (score 18):

You don't "transfer" an account to an other email address. You add another OpenID account to your existing Stack Overflow account. The procedure is [outlined in the Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/edit-credentials).

So first create your new email address, add it as an OpenID provider to your account and then remove your current (old) one.

Then you should be good to go.