# Change OpenID email address

Tags: support

How can I change the email address I use to log into SO? I tried adding logins but it doesn't prompt me to add my new email address.

Comment: which open id are you using?

Comment: google open id.

Comment: and you want to add a different Google account?  Or something else?

Comment: i would like to replace my current google email address I use to login in via open id with a new google email address.

Comment: So you tried to do this by going to "my logins" and attempting to add your second email? Just trying to understand what you've tried so far, as your question is not clear on this.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can I transfer my SO account to a new email address?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252545/can-i-transfer-my-so-account-to-a-new-email-address)

Comment: @Kendra, yes. I logged into Safari with my current email address. SO recognises that I am logged in and automatically authenticates and let me into SO. I click on "my logins", then "add more logins", it then displays a page with buttons. I click on the "add a login using Google" and it takes me back to my summary page. It doesn't let me add a new login.

Comment: @psubsee2003 That question might not actually help the user here. [There was a question yesterday about adding multiple Google logins](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285788/can-i-add-more-than-one-google-account-under-my-logins?noredirect=1#comment153794_285788) and if this user is experiencing the same issue, I would assume that method won't help fix this issue.

Comment: @Kendra give it a minute and there will be an answer that does help.  IIRC you can't have multiple logins of the same type on your account, so you need to add a temp one of another type (Facebook, Yahoo, etc), remove the old one, then add the new one

Comment: @psubsee2003 Really? Do you happen to have a source for that? I couldn't find anything that said that yesterday, and when I tried with Yahoo (my current login source) I got sent to the authentication page, not redirected to my profile.

Comment: @Kendra trying to find - it would be somewhere on MSE

Comment: @Kendra you only get redirected to your profile if you try to add one for an account type you already are using.  It should be (1) Add Temp  (2) Remove old (3) Add New (4) Optional - Remove temp.

Comment: @psubsee2003 [I found one from Anna Lear stating we can have multiple Google logins.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/159832/266735) I figured it out, however, what is causing this issue.

Comment: I.K, [this answer should help you.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/134386/266735) Follow these steps, then you can remove the old account from your logins list.

Comment: @Kendra that is probably what I was remembering - it is very similar except removing the old one.

Comment: @Kendra, thanks but I don't get option 4 to add the desired google account

Comment: @Kendra, I will contact support. Others have mentioned that it didn't work for them either. THere's probably something wrong with my account.

Comment: I.K., that part is actually done on Google itself. I'm writing an answer to the first question I linked to, since that was specifically how to add a second Google account.